# Total output for scanf

Tags: c

The program that I am trying to come out with is the total amount of times/entries scanf has been keyed in by the user excluding 0. I can't seem to get the system not to include 0 as part of the entries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
int amt, entries;
amt = 1
while (amt!=0)
{
prinf("Enter amount: ", amt);
entries+=scanf("%d", &amt);
}
printf("\nNumber of entries: %d", entries);
}
```

If I were to key in 5, 6, 7, 9, 0 the output that I would get for the number of entries is 5. How can I change my program to not include 0 as part of my entry? The final outcome that I am trying to achieve to get is 4 for the number of entries instead of 5

Comment: Why not just print `entries - 1`? You know that you will get an additional entry for the terminating `0`, so just remove it from the total amount.

Comment: For starters indent your code properly.

Comment: @Amil, When `entries+=scanf("%d", &amt);` is first executed, what is the initial value of `entries`?

Comment: `void main` is not standard.

Comment: @RinkeshP C standard  has "or in some other implementation-defined manner" appears to allow `void main(void)`.

Comment: Quite a few issues in your code, all of which can be corrected. However, you need to clarify. Do you want to read all numbers on one input (one line), or one at a time, in a loop?

Comment: @Amil, Try `int entries = -1;`